# jQuery return false not stopping scrolling on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample HTML response from server after input:

```
<ul class="datalistPlaceholder hidden" style="display: block;">
    <li><a class="tag" href="#">#<span style="font-weight: bold">ar</span>igato</a></li>
    <li><a class="tag" href="#">#<span style="font-weight: bold">ar</span>izona</a></li>
    <li><a class="tag" href="#">#cle<span style="font-weight: bold">ar</span>water</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#search-field').keyup(function(e) {
        ajaxAutocomplete.call(this, e);
    });
});

function ajaxAutocomplete(e) {
    var hash_tag = $.trim($(this).val());

    $.ajax({
        url     : 'autocomplete.php',
        method  : 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data    : {tag : hash_tag}
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        if (response) {
            $('.datalistPlaceholder').html(response).show();

            if (e.keyCode === 40) { // down key
                $('.tag:first').focus();
                $('.tag').keydown(function(e) {
                    down.call(this, e);
                });
            } else if (e.keyCode === 38) { // up key
            }
        } else {
            $('.datalistPlaceholder').hide();
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('Something went wrong');
    });
}

function down(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        $(this).parent('li').next().find('.tag').focus();
        // stops page from scrolling
        return false;
    }
}
```

When the user uses the down arrow key to select an option from the drop down menu the page scrolls. I thought returning false would prevent this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of doing `ajaxAutocomplete.call(this, e);` why dont you just do: `$('#search-field').keyup(ajaxAutocomplete);` ?

Comment: Because i need to know what key was pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have this:

```
$('.tag').keydown(function(e) {
    down.call(this, e);
});
```

Not sure why you are doing it that way instead of just using `down` directly but you aren't returning whatever `down()` returns so your anonymous callback function will be returning `undefined` instead of `false`

Either use `down` directly as the callback function or do the extra return

```
$('.tag').keydown(down);
//or
$('.tag').keydown(function(e) {
    return down.call(this,e)
});
```

Note you could also call `e.preventDefault()` instead of returning false to prevent default actions.

As a side note doing `$('.tag').keydown(function(e)...` everytime in your `done` callback is going to keep adding new event handlers for those elements that might not get destroyed by `$('.datalistPlaceholder').html(response)`. You can use a delegated event so that you only have to create the handler once:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.datalistPlaceholder').on("keydown",".tag",down);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @patrick! I was doing as above due to lack of experience. Your answer was very helpful and I now know and have more experience.